# "webkit-appearance: checkbox" works improperly in iOS

Tags: css, checkbox, radio-button

I use attribute to style my radio buttons to make it look like checkbox. it works successfully on chrome, firefox, safari on window. but problem exists when the webpage was opened in Safari on iOS. The problem is that it still appear as checkbox, but they are **round in shape like radiobutton**. that means when you click it, it stills display a tick, but what wrapped the tick is a circle, not a square.

So how to fix this problem? any idea?

Comment: I realise this is outside the scope of your question and I'm sure you've got good reasons to want to style a radio button with a tick. However you should ask yourself about the usability of such a choice, normally people will expect a "ticked" interface to be able to select multiple items and a radio buttoned interface to select only one. http://ux.stackexchange.com (stackoverflow's sister site) is a great resource for usability.

Comment: .row.five input[type="radio"]{
    -webkit-appearance: checkbox;
    -moz-appearance: checkbox;
}

Comment: @AlexKey i know what you mean. but it's user requirement lol

Answer (score 1):

Below `-webkit-appearance: checkbox;`, put  `-webkit-border-radius: 5px;` (or whatever other size you want for the kind of corners you desire).

Comment: I noticed that adding
width:auto; and height:auto;
would help if you want to style the radio buttons as normal buttons.